# Get Theme and Wordpress version details via API

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

wordpress gives API for all plugins including change log , version , details, screenshots..etc in http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress.org_API

For example 
https://api.wordpress.org/plugins/info/1.0/BuddyPress

Same way themes and wordpress every version i need to get these details. i have tried with https://api.wordpress.org/themes/info/1.1/
and it shows nothing and i do not know where to modify  this api url to get particular details of a theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `$request` parameter to pass the arguments, for example to get infos on *Twentyfifteen* theme:

https://api.wordpress.org/themes/info/1.1/?action=theme_information&request[slug]=twentyfifteen

Or to get the first 3 themes by the author *Wordpress.org*:

https://api.wordpress.org/themes/info/1.1/?action=query_themes&request[author]=wordpressdotorg&request[per_page]=3

Comment: Nice, very helpful bit of query strings there... the codex doesn't make it 100% clear